# Scroll bar stays in same position from one website to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to click on a link in my HTML website and when I load onto the other website to be in the same position. Say you are in the middle of a website when you click the link I want to be in the middle of the website when I load onto that link. Is there anyway to do this? Sorry if this is confusing.

I'm sorry for the confusion, but I meant if you controlled both web pages. My bad.

Comment: what ??? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you are asking, as I understand it, is not possible-- you cannot execute your own code on someone else's website, unless this is in the context of a browser plugin/addon you are creating, in which case the question should be updated to reflect that.

Comment: You can link it to div of the other page by id somesite.com#someID

Comment: What you *may* be thinking of that you have seen on some sites is the ability to link to a specific element by including the element's `id` in a hash-- however, this is very different from linking to an arbitrary scroll position.

Comment: If you control the other website then when clicking on that link send the Y coordinate to the database and before loading the other page execute the scroll method with the Y coordinate  retrieved from the database

Comment: If you truly need "scroll position" and not just an anchor or tag as others have mentioned, you could use a browser extension to achieve that effect, otherwise, youd have to control both sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way unless you have control over the linked site.

Scrollbar is rendered by the browser based on `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` attributes, if you have no control over the linked site's code, you can't force it to present a `scrollbar` or `scroll` to a specific position(which requires `javascript` code to be executed)

If you have access to the linked site's code, you can send the `ID` of the `element` you want to scroll to through the `url` as a parameter like this:

```
https://example.net#mydiv
```

and then, at the linked site, just add this `javascript` code to scroll to the element:

```
$(window).load(() => {
    const divID = window.location.hash;
    document.getElementById(divID).scrollIntoView();
});
```